# Proof of variation Jensen's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I was reading a book which was explaining about Rolle's theorem and Mean Value theorem when I saw this question:
[image]

I'm not at all sure how do I go about for the proof of this question, and apart from realizing that f being convex implies $f^\prime$ is increasing, I haven't made much progress on this question.

Any hint as to how to solve this question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation that $f'$ is nondecreasing is good. You can use the mean value theorem to relate the given inequality with $f'$.

Without loss of generality assume $x < y$. The mean value theorem implies
$$\frac{f(y) - f((x+y)/2)}{(y-x)/2} = f'(\xi_2)$$ for some $\xi_2 \in [(x+y)/2, y]$. Similarly,
$$\frac{f((x+y)/2)-f(x)}{(y-x)/2} = f'(\xi_1)$$ for some $\xi_1 \in [x, (x+y)/2]$. Now use what you observed about $f'$ in your post.

Comment: Oh I understand now, thank you so much.